# Why is process.env undefined in module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm beginner with nodejs and I want environment variables shared through modules. I read those variables with dotenv package. But in next required module process.env is undefined.

app.js

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config())
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
require('./task')
```

task.js

```
console.log(process.env);
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8080
```

console log

```
{ parsed: { NODE_ENV: 'development', PORT: '8080' } }
development
undefined
E:\msf\nodejs_prj\compositor\task.js:2
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'NODE_ENV' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> ...
```

---

I created new clean project with provided code and it works also for me. That means it's related to something else. This node.js is weard about errors.

This is my whole code from task.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const decompress = require('decompress')

const dir = './upload'

console.log(process, process.env)

function process() {
    console.log('cron - process data');

    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) return

        files.forEach(file => {
            if (path.extname(file) != '.zip') return

            let target = path.join(dir, path.basename(file).replace(path.extname(file), ''))
            unlinkDirSync(target)

            decompress(path.join(dir, file), target).then(files => {
                console.log(files);
                console.log('done!');

                //todo process unzipped files

                //todo delete unzipped directory and zip file
            })
        })
    })
}

function unlinkDirSync(dir_path) {
    if (fs.existsSync(dir_path)) {
        fs.readdirSync(dir_path).forEach(function (entry) {
            var entry_path = path.join(dir_path, entry);
            if (fs.lstatSync(entry_path).isDirectory()) {
                unlinkDirSync(entry_path);
            } else {
                fs.unlinkSync(entry_path);
            }
        });
        fs.rmdirSync(dir_path);
    }
}

if (process.env === undefined || process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log('starting on production')
    setInterval(process, 1000 * 60)
} else {
    console.log('starting on development')
    setTimeout(process, 1000)
}
```

If I comment out the rest after console.log it works.

Comment: it's working fine on my machine, same code

Comment: Same, can't reproduce the issue (Ubuntu v18.04, Node v12.4, dotenv v8.0.0)

Comment: how do you run application and which versions (node, dotenv) are you using?

Comment: I've Win10, node.js v10.16.0, dotenv 8.0.0

Comment: [process.env](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) should never be undefined. @EsooLDo are you ***sure*** the whole code you're using has been included in the question?

Comment: is it *exactly* the same code you are running?
could you `console.log(process)` in `task.js`?

Comment: @EsooLDo It is because you are requiring the `task.js ` which is imported and executed before the compilation and console.log() is printed before starting the node application.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that sounds like a deal. What can do with it?

Comment: @EsooLDo its happening because you have a function named `process` in `task.js` rename it to some other name, as process is a global object  used to provide information about current nodejs process

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm idiot. I named function process, which is the name of system variable :D

Sorry for bothering you guys, thanks for help.

Comment: Haha, that's too funny, I just had exactly the same problem.  Only once I printed out the value of "process" to the console did I realise what I'd done.

Comment: I'm an idiot too, thanks :) hahahahha I mean , I'm searching this for almost one day. Waiting an extraordinary solution than you appear with a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Add **require('dotenv').config()** in global. Also make sure .env file is in root directory of the project. I have created a sample on github https://github.com/GMaker01/basic-dotenv-example

For reference, you can look into the dotenv [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)